# Connect label with the control it represents

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, user-interface

I've been pondering on this problem for some time now. Is there a *neat* way to "connect" a `Label` with a control it's labeling in a functional way?

For example, you have a form to create a new user profile. If a user doesn't fill out a necessary field, the `Label` of that `TextBox`, or `NumericUpDown` or what not, turn red. Somehow, the `Label` has to know which `Control` it belongs to, and vice versa.

What I do right now is search for the correct label by its `.Name` property, which matcher (partly) with the `.Name` property of my text box. That ugly method looks somewhat like this (VB.NET):

```
Dim redLabel As Label

For Each txt As Control In Me.Controls
    If (TypeOf txt Is TextBox And txt.Text = "") Or _
       (TypeOf txt Is NumericUpDown And txt.Text = "0") Then

        'Change corresponding label color to red'
        redLabel = CType(Me.Controls.Find("Label" & _
                         txt.Name.Remove(0, "TextBox".Length), True)(0), Label)
        redLabel.ForeColor = Color.Red
        'Get name of the non-filled field'
        boxesNotFilled.Add(redLabel.Text)

    End If
Next
```

I could make a custom control that does the job, but I don't want to if I don't have to (the classic problem of reinventing the wheel). The question logically follows: is there a way to provide for such interaction between controls without searching for them and using *not-at-all-safe* control naming as convention, without writing custom controls?

Cheers! = )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with a custom `UserControl` for something like this.  It takes less time to write a simple UserControl than it does to post a question to StackOverflow. :)

Comment: I agree. And I've been doing that too. The question is about coding practices more than anything else.

Comment: I see also that you ended your question with "... without writing custom controls". My bad.

Answer (score 0):

How about just starting with a [RequiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx)?   That'll give you the ControlToValidate property at runtime.